# How we can achieve Microservices related functionality with Loopback Framework

Tags: node.js, microservices, strongloop, loopback

I need your help in Loopback Framework.
Actually, my need is how we can achieve Microservices related functionality with Loopback Framework.

Please share any links/tutorials/knowledge if you have any.
I have gone through below links,
https://strongloop.com/strongblog/creating-a-multi-tenant-connector-microservice-using-loopback/

I have downloaded the related demo from below links but doesn't work it.
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback4-example-microservices
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-facade

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Basically it depends on your budget and size of your system. You can make some robust and complex implementations using tools like [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) or [KrakenD](http://www.krakend.io/). As a matter of fact, your question is too broad. I've some microservices architecture knowledge and I can recommend just splitting your functionality into containerized solutions, probably orchestrated by Kubernetes. In that way, you can expose for example, the User microservice with loopback, and another Authentication microservice with loopback and/or any other language/framework.

You could (but shouldn't) add communication between those microservices (as you should expose some REST functionality) with something like [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).

The biggest cloud providers have some already made solutions, eg AWS has [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) or [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). For GCP you have [Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/).

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for your response. 

Do you have any link or example in LoopBack in which Microservices related functionality implemented.

Thanks,

Comment: Sure, [here is a repo demonstrating microservices usage with loopback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-facade/wiki/The-Microservice-Facade-Pattern)

Comment: @RodrigoMata that example is about facade pattern. A facade service is simple because it just for purpose expose API. So do you have any tut explain that how to dev a particular microservice with loopback. Tks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have created an open source catalog of microservices which can be used in any microservice project using LB4. Also, you can get an idea of how to create microservices using LB4. https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-microservice-catalog